# How do I determine the number of files that contain a particular word using numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a group of files each with containing a letter and a number. (A4, for example). Each file only either has A or B before the number and I want to know how to determine the number of files that have an A in them.

This is what I've done so far. The output looks like this:
1
0
0
1
1
0.. ect.

```
import numpy as np

filename_start = 'temp'
list_of_file_nums = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21
                    ,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29]
filename_end = '.txt'
for n in list_of_file_nums:
  
     if list_of_file_nums[n] <=  9:
        filenumber = list_of_file_nums[n]
        filename = filename_start + str(0)+ str(filenumber) +filename_end
     else:
        filenumber = list_of_file_nums[n]
        filename = filename_start + str(filenumber) + filename_end
        
        
  
     with open(filename,'r') as file:
         number =0
         line = file.read()
         letter = line.split()
         for i in letter:
             if i == 'A':
              number += 1
```

I did this to try and then sum all the 1's together to get the total files that contain A.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would need numpy for this scenario and also you should define the variable ***number*** outside the loop so that you can do the arthimetic properly. Since you have defined the variable inside the loop it redefines itself as 0 for each file.

```
number = 0
for....:
   with open(filename,'r') as file:
      line = file.read()
      llist = list(line)
      if "A" in llist:
         number = number + 1
```